Rod bending by blend tree in Unity
I'm working on implementing rod bending by blend tree.
Once, I've made a system to achieve that but then after I found out it doesn't work correctly in every angles and situations.
I fills directionX (First parameter of blend tree) and directionY (Second parameter of blend tree) by using this code:
            Vector3 projectedLineXY = Vector3.ProjectOnPlane(_baitHandler.transform.position - _context.rodTip.position, _context.rod.transform.forward);
            float angleSignXY = Mathf.Sign(Vector3.Dot(Vector3.Cross(_context.rod.transform.up, projectedLineXY), _context.rod.transform.forward));
            float angleXY = Vector3.Angle(_context.rod.transform.up, projectedLineXY) * angleSignXY;
            Vector3 projectedLineZY = Vector3.ProjectOnPlane(_baitHandler.transform.position - _context.rodTip.position, _context.rod.transform.right);
            float angleSignZY = Mathf.Sign(Vector3.Dot(Vector3.Cross(_context.rod.transform.up, projectedLineZY), -_context.rod.transform.right));
            float angleZY = Vector3.Angle(_context.rod.transform.up, projectedLineZY) * angleSignZY;

_baitHandler.transform.position is bait position and _context.rodTip.position is tip of rod position. _context.rod is rod gameObject and other things related to that are its directions.
Please if you know how I can achieve the correct solution for that, explain what exactly I can fill these 2 parameters of blend tree.
Video from blend tree

Maybe it's just me, but I don't really understand / see what exactly the question or issue is .. or what exactly you are trying to achieve in the first place

You don't understand the code or the blend tree ? First of all, as you might know, rod when is in hand, it can't rotate based on the force so rotation should happen on the top parts, so because of that, we have side rotations. About the code, I'm trying to find 2 angles to fill those 2 blend tree parameters based on the selected planes which their normals are not global axes and they are rod or tip of the rod directions. Based on these angles I can find out how much it need to be rotated. @derHugo

I think my appraoch is correct but something is off and I can't find the solution. But even I might be totally wrong about the appraoch I chose or even my blend tree setup. I'm really stuck here for a few days after testing so many details in my code.

Do you absolutely need the blendtree or just a solution?

You could look into physics joints if you need physics. You could also use Animation Rigging (e.g. a Chain IK).

I hope it is helpful for anyone who is looking for implementing rod bending by blend tree.
Finally I got to this after so many iterations:
private const float ROD_BEND_CORRECTION_ERROR = 0.01f;
private readonly int DIRECTION_X_HASH = Animator.StringToHash("directionX");
private readonly int DIRECTION_Y_HASH = Animator.StringToHash("directionY");

public void UpdateRodBend(float deltaTime, float strength = 1f)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        Vector3 line = bait.position - rodTip.position;
        Vector3 projectedY = Vector3.ProjectOnPlane(line, rodTip.forward);
        float angleSignY = Mathf.Sign(Vector3.Dot(Vector3.Cross(rodTip.up, projectedY), rodTip.forward));
        float angleY = Vector3.Angle(-rodTip.up, projectedY) * angleSignY;
        if (Mathf.Abs(angleY / 90) > ROD_BEND_CORRECTION_ERROR)
        {
            animator.SetDirectionY((angleY / 90) * deltaTime * rodBendingSmoothSpeed, strength);
            animator.ForceUpdateRodAnimator();
        }
        line = bait.position - rodTip.position;
        Vector3 projectedX = Vector3.ProjectOnPlane(line, rodTip.right);
        float angleSignX = Mathf.Sign(Vector3.Dot(Vector3.Cross(_context.rodTip.up, projectedX), -rodTip.right));
        float angleX = Vector3.Angle(-rodTip.up, projectedX) * angleSignX;
        if (Mathf.Abs(angleX / 90) > ROD_BEND_CORRECTION_ERROR)
        {
            animator.SetDirectionX((angleX / 90) * deltaTime * rodBendingSmoothSpeed, strength);
            animator.ForceUpdateRodAnimator();
        }
    }
}

public void SetDirectionX(float value, float maxLength)
{
    Vector2 clamped = Vector2.ClampMagnitude(new Vector2(animator.GetFloat(DIRECTION_X_HASH) + value, animator.GetFloat(DIRECTION_Y_HASH)), maxLength);
    animator.SetFloat(DIRECTION_X_HASH, clamped.x);
}

public void SetDirectionY(float value, float maxLength)
{
    Vector2 clamped = Vector2.ClampMagnitude(new Vector2(animator.GetFloat(DIRECTION_X_HASH), animator.GetFloat(DIRECTION_Y_HASH) + value), maxLength);
    animator.SetFloat(DIRECTION_Y_HASH, clamped.y);
}

